# Selecting a random start point on simple 2d array game

Tags: java, arrays

Create a 7x7 multidimensional array.

- Put random numbers between [1, 100] inside the array cells FillBoard(int[][]):void
- Select a random row and column to start the game (should not be a wall).
- **Create a method called “PrintBoard(int[][], int x, int y): void” that prints the board. Surround the current cell with pipes: E.g. “|64|”**

So this is my task for quiz but I stucked at bolded section. 
Can you help me please?

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Answer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int board[][] = fillBoard(7, 7);
        Random start = new Random();
        int startX = start.nextInt(7);
        int startY = start.nextInt(7);
        System.out.println("StartX: " + startX + " StartY: " + startY );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----Initial Board----");
        System.out.println();
        printBoard(board,startX,startY);

    }


    public static int [][] fillBoard (int row, int column){
        int [][] array = new int [row][column];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    public static void printBoard(int [][] array, int x, int y) {
        Random st = new Random();
        x = st.nextInt(7);
        y = st.nextInt(7);
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And how are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you give `x` and `y` as parameter, don't change their values in the method
2. Compare `x,y` with the indice `i,j` to know where to put the pipes
3. To get a good alignement (because of 1-digit number and 2-digit number) I'd suggest to use `printf("%2d, value);`

```
public static void printBoard(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == x && j == y) {
                System.out.printf("|%2d|\t", array[i][j]);
            } else {
                System.out.printf(" %2d \t", array[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnılCan you're welcome. look the edit, I've changed lines for printing to get a good alignement

Answer (score 1):

From this I guess you are stuck at printing the *cell pipes*?

> Create a method called “PrintBoard(int[][], int x, int y): void” that
>   prints the board. Surround the current cell with pipes: E.g. “|64|”

In that case change your method to this one bellow:

```
public static void printBoard(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
    Random st = new Random();
    x = st.nextInt(7);
    y = st.nextInt(7);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("|" + array[i][j] + "|" + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
StartX: 5 StartY: 6

----Initial Board----

|74|    |95|    |31|    |12|    |26|    |3| |3| 
|87|    |59|    |84|    |73|    |67|    |44|    |47|    
|35|    |71|    |55|    |44|    |10|    |75|    |60|    
|68|    |49|    |85|    |43|    |87|    |31|    |33|    
|30|    |97|    |45|    |82|    |60|    |25|    |68|    
|28|    |32|    |88|    |83|    |82|    |34|    |21|    
|6| |20|    |5| |85|    |67|    |75|    |53|
```